# Get users which are not stated in the query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Well I have gotten this query:

```
$characterinfoquery = "
SELECT 
    c.Name, 
    c.Level, 
    c.Sex, 
    c.Playtime, 
    c.KillCount, 
    c.DeathCount,
    cl.Name AS clanName
FROM 
    Character AS c, 
    Account AS a,
    ClanMember AS cm,
    Clan AS cl
WHERE 
    c.AccountID = a.AccountID AND
    c.CharacterID = cm.CharacterID AND
    cm.ClanID = cl.ClanID AND
    a.UserID='".mssql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'
";
```

But I want the members who do not have a clan to be showed too but instead of the clan name it would say "-" at where the clan name is supposed to be.

This is my while statement:

```
if(mssql_num_rows($characterinforesult) != 0){
    $content = str_replace("%content%", file_get_contents("tpl/contents/characterinfo.html"), $content);

    //Get character information
    $search = array("%Name%", "%Level%", "%Sex%", "%Playtime%", "%KillDeath%", "%Clan%");
    $rows = file_get_contents("tpl/contents/characterinfo_tr.html");
    while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($characterinforesult)){

        if($row['KillCount'] != 0){
            $KillDeath = round($row['KillCount']/$row['DeathCount'], 2);
        }
        else{
            $KillDeath = "-";
        }
        $Playtime = $row['Playtime']/60;
        $replace = array($row['Name'], $row['Level'], gender($row['Sex']), round($Playtime), $KillDeath, $row['clanName']);
        $tr .= str_replace($search, $replace, $rows);
    }
}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Output with innerjoins:

```
Name    Level   Sex     Playtime    K/D Ratio   Clan
DragonDex   97  Male    375 min     0.22            Test
```

It shows 1 row while there are 2 characters in that account, 1 has a clan the other doesn't.

Comment: You want an `outer join` which will return queries whether or not they match one of your tables. The syntax will depend on the database you are using. You should add the right tag for the database to your question.

Comment: Yea sorry, done that now. So how do I set this up?

Comment: I don't know sql-server much, but the answer from @danihp looks like proper ansi, so +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need a left outer join:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name, 
    c.Level, 
    c.Sex, 
    c.Playtime, 
    c.KillCount, 
    c.DeathCount,
    coalesce( cl.Name, ' - ' ) AS clanName
FROM 
    Character AS c 
          inner join  
    Account AS a 
          on c.AccountID = a.AccountID
          left outer join 
    ClanMember AS cm 
          on c.CharacterID = cm.CharacterID
          left outer join 
    Clan AS cl
          on cm.ClanID = cl.ClanID
WHERE 
    a.UserID='".mssq ...
```

Comment: Sorry but it didnt work.. I have put the output in my editted post

Comment: I editted my output. There was a mistake of mine. Now I have only the members with a clan showing. The one's without are not being showed.

Comment: yes. You need 2 outer joins. Sorry. I fix the answer. Try again!

Comment: Regards @SinanSamet, Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you, these inner and outer joins confuse me a little but I will try to learn it as it seems really usefull at times.